# Crear una app de React con Vite, no me abre el localhost 3000 ¿cómo podría cambiarlo?

Tags: reactjs, localhost, vite

Hola que tal estoy empezando un curso de react y en lugar de crear las aplicaciones con create-react-app, estoy probando otras alternativas como es usar la terminal powershell y vite con el comando `npm create vite@latest`, le sigue nombre del proyecto, tecnología (react), y elegir react sin typescript. Hecho esto, se crea el nuevo directorio, nos vamos a él, instalamos los paquetes y ejecutamos `npm run dev`, básicamente el **get started** de vite, en todos los vídeos que veo para tomar referencias, a la gente se le ejecuta el localhost:3000 o 3001, sin embargo a mí me abre uno bien distinto, y la pantalla inicial que aparece en local no es la misma. Estoy leyendo en la documentación de vite, https://vitejs.dev/guide/#trying-vite-online que requiere node 14.18+ y mi versión actual es 14.16.0 y mi versión npm es 6.14.11, así que no sé si actualizando node a la última versión lts podría resolverse mi problema.
Aquí viene mi segunda pregunta entonces, si actualizo node y con ello imagino que npm también se actualiza, ¿a mis proyectos actuales les pasaría algo por dicha actualización? Como que dejasen de funcionar o algo por estilo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por defecto esta usando el puerto 5173, si deseas cambiarlo ve al archivo "vite.config.js" y agrega configuración del "server" para cambiar el puerto:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  }
})
```

Comment: Pero eso debo hacerlo con cada proyecto que inicialice con vite? Lo digo porque todos los canales que veo, al crear el directorio y tal, ya les viene por defecto ese puerto 3000 + una pantalla inicial distinta, lo dejaría así pero no sé si a raíz de esto podría tener problemas de compatibilidades a futuro.

Comment: Si incluso la pantalla inicial es diferente, es posible que cuando grabaron el video, vite haya estado en otra versión. Entonces la versión actual tiene otra pantalla de inicio y usa el puerto 5173 para react por defecto.

Comment: Pues sí tienes razón, pero vamos ha tenido que ser un cambio muy reciente, porque vídeos de pocos meses te abría localhost 3000 con otra pantalla. Y respecto a lo de actualizar node, sabes si dejarían de correr proyectos míos actuales? no debería no?

Comment: Así es, siempre van sacando nuevas versiones, [en este enlace](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/releases) puedes ver que la última versión salió hace 2 días. Sobre lo de node, no debería afectar si son proyectos recientes.

Comment: Tremendo gracias por compartir ese enlace, efectivamente el 13 de julio de 2022 se cambió el puerto y el host, e imagino que con esto la plantilla también ha variado. Muchas gracias.